# Compiling Apache from LLVM IR files

Tags: apache, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to compile apache2 from LLVM IR intermediate files.

I was able to compile apache2 with clang and generate apaches executables accompanied with LLVM IR intermediate files. I was able to run some optimizations on some of the LLVM IR intermediate files. Now i want to regenerate the apache2 executable from the new/modified LLVM-IR files to compare the performance of the two executables.

I used llvm-llc to generate object files from the generated llvm-files, and now when i try to link all the object files using clang, i get erros. Below is just a sample of the errors i get:

```
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr-util/ldap/apr_ldap_init.c:92: undefined reference to `ldap_err2string'
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr-util/ldap/apr_ldap_option.c:603: undefined reference to `ldap_set_option'
/home/yousif/fuzz-testing/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr-util/xml/apr_xml.c:380: undefined reference to `XML_StopParser'
dso.o: In function `dso_cleanup':
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/dso/unix/dso.c:72: undefined reference to `dlclose'
dso.o: In function `apr_dso_load':
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/dso/unix/dso.c:139: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/dso/unix/dso.c:153: undefined reference to `dlerror'
dso.o: In function `apr_dso_sym':
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/dso/unix/dso.c:227: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/dso/unix/dso.c:231: undefined reference to `dlerror'
proc_mutex.o: In function `proc_mutex_pthread_acquire_ex':
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/locks/unix/proc_mutex.c:807: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_timedlock'
/apache/httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr/locks/unix/proc_mutex.c:788: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'

....
```

I am guessing that i am missing a lot of the object files or libraries that are needed in the linking phase in order to generate the final executable.

My questions is how and where can i find all the object files that are needed in order to be able to regenerate the apache executable?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to link the libraries like pthreads and libdl. You could look what is necessary from the ordinary linker cmdline obviously.